# If and Mid functions need help please

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a list of VIN numbers (17 characters) and the 10th character is the model year - which could be a letter or a number. I read somewhere that `IF` functions will only accept 7 levels, I have 16 levels of conditions:

```
G   2016
F   2015
E   2014
D   2013
C   2012
B   2011
A   2010
9   2009
8   2008
7   2007
6   2006
5   2005
4   2004
3   2003
2   2002
1   2001
```

I started creating the formula (just a few levels, not the entire 16) but the value I get back is `FALSE`.

```
=IF(MID(A1,10,1)=1,2001,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=2,2002,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=3,2003,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=4,2004,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=5,2005,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=6,2006,
IF(MID(A1,10,1)=7,2007
)))))))
```

Perhaps a different combination of formulas will work better?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
=CInt(MID(A1,9,2)) + 2000
```

It works as long as the year is a 2000 year and is never a character.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
=IFERROR(2000 + HEX2DEC(MID(A1,10,1)),2016)
```

If you don't want to use IFERROR you can use this slightly longer formula

```
=IF(MID(A1,10,1)="G",2016,2000 + HEX2DEC(MID(A1,10,1)))
```

By the way,  Excel 2007 allows 64 nested ifs now

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a lookup table, e.g. if the codes are listed in `Y2:Y17` and years in `Z2:Z17` you can use this formula

`=VLOOKUP(MID(A1,10,1),Y$2:Z$17,2,0)`

Note that `MID` function always returns a text result so the `Y2:Y17` range of the lookup table should be text formatted (even the numbers), so either format that range as text before you enter the data or enter the numbers with a preceeding apostrophe like '4

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote this because the last one didn't take into account the letters:

=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,10,1))),MID(A1,10,1)+2000,CODE(UPPER(B1))+1945)

It works by detecting if the 10th char is a number, if it is then add 2000 to it, if it is a letter then it breaks it down to the ASCII value (65 for A) and adds 1945 to it. Note, I used Upper as lowercase a is 97 which would make the result wrong. If you are guaranteed your vin numbers are all caps then you can omit the upper clause

Comment: Out of interest, how does the VIN deal with pre 2000 cars?

Comment: Thank you Dan for responding so quickly. Learning lots from you guys :)

Comment: Sorry missed your question Dan. It uses 1 to 9 then A to Y (skips some letters) and then goes back to 1. For this paticular manufacturer anyway. So... 2000 is Y, 1999 is X, etc.

Comment: OK, the above formula will not work for the pre 2001 scenario in this case.